# Polynomial with roots of unity as roots but real coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial of the following form
$$p(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x - e^{2 \pi i \alpha_j}) = x^n + A_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + A_1 x + A_0$$
for $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{C}$ as well $A_j \in \mathbb{C}$ for all $j=1,...,n$. Then clearly the roots of $p(x)$ are $a_j = e^{2 \pi i \alpha_j}$ and $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. My question now is the following:

If we additionally assume that all $a_j$ are $n$-th roots of unity, i.e. $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$ and invariant under  $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ in the sense, that $\{a_1,...,a_n\}=\{a_1^{-1},...,a_n^{-1}\}$. Does this imply that the coefficients $A_j \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: It surely is possible. Are you asking if it is *only possible* if all coefficients are real?

Comment: $e^{2 \pi i \alpha_j}$ with $\alpha_j \in \Bbb C$ is not necessarily a “root of unity” – can you clarify the question?

Comment: yes, i rewrite it so that it hopefully becomes clearer. But thanks for commenting anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true, and it suffices to require that all roots $a_j$ have modulus one, i.e. $\alpha_j \in \Bbb R$.

Since
$$
\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}=\{a_1^{-1},\ldots,a_n^{-1}\} = \{\overline{a_1},\ldots,\overline{a_n}\}
$$
it follows that
$$
p(x) = (x-a_1) \cdots (x-a_n) = (x-\overline{a_1}) \cdots (x-\overline{a_n})
$$
and that implies that all coefficients $A_j$ of $p$ satisfy $A_j = \overline{A_j}$, i.e. all coefficients of $p$ are real.

Answer (score 2):

If $\omega$ is a root of unity other than  $\pm 1$ then $\overline {\omega}$ is also a root of unity.  And $(x-\omega)(x-\overline {\omega})=x^{2}-|w|^{2}-2\Re (x\overline {\omega})$ for $x$ real. Hence, the coefficients of $p(x)$ are necesarily real when the roots of $p$ are the $n-$th roots of unity.